# trouble adding calculated variables c#

Tags: c#, try-catch, formatexception

Basically, I need to add resulta + resultb + resultc + the previously defined propertyPrice together to get a total, then show the total in a text box. Resulta/b/c are calculated based off propertyPrice * a constant, property price is input by the user.

I did it without try-catch and was getting format exceptions.

```
int propertyPrice;

if (Int32.TryParse(propertyPriceTextBox.Text, out propertyPrice))
{
    stateSalesTaxTextBox.Text = (stateSalesTax * propertyPrice).ToString("c");

    if (residentialRadioButton.Checked == true)
        comissionTextBox.Text = (residentialCom * propertyPrice).ToString("c");

    if (commercialRadioButton.Checked == true)
        comissionTextBox.Text = (commercialCom * propertyPrice).ToString("c");

    if (hillsRadioButton.Checked == true)
        countySalesTaxTextBox.Text = (hilssTax * propertyPrice).ToString("c");

    if (pascoRadioButton.Checked == true)
        countySalesTaxTextBox.Text = (pascoTax * propertyPrice).ToString("c");

    if (polkRadioButton.Checked == true)
        countySalesTaxTextBox.Text = (polkTax * propertyPrice).ToString("c");

    decimal resulta;
    decimal resultb;
    decimal resultc;

    try
    {
        resulta = decimal.Parse(countySalesTaxTextBox.Text);
        resultb = decimal.Parse(stateSalesTaxTextBox.Text);
        resultc = decimal.Parse(comissionTextBox.Text);
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {


    }

    decimal totalPrice = (resulta + resultb + resultc + propertyPrice);
    totalPriceTextBox.Text = totalPrice.ToString("c");  
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do when one of your text boxes fails?

Comment: Did you check *why* you were getting format exceptions? You need to see what the problematic input was, then decide if you want to accept that input (or alert the user to the error) and what to do when it occurs.

Comment: This looks like a good case for using a custom control that only accepts numeric values.

Comment: Bear in mind you should each variable individually, since each of them may cause you a FormatException - this would not allow to know each one raise the exception.

Comment: @NickHebb Yeah, the professor wants it this way even though that way is much easier. :(

Comment: @JamaulSmith Sounds like the prof might be teaching you a lesson about parsing then! Learning anything? :-)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Learning more about sleep deprivation and headaches. So yeah, parsing. everyone's been so helpful, It's incredible, so many wise people, I've learned quite a bit in this thread TBH.

Comment: @JamaulSmith you should not drastically edit the code in your question.  Your edit invalidated several answers already posted.  Instead if you add the addtional information, but not replace what is already there.

Comment: @JamaulSmith I added the newer bits of code back for you.  Hopefully this adds what you wanted with out changing too much of your question.  Feel free to edit it as you want, but try not to change the validity of answers when you make an edit.

Answer (score 3):

Use `decimal.TryParse`; this will allow you to check whether the string is valid or not.

```
decimal resulta;
decimal resultb;
decimal resultc;

if (!decimal.TryParse(countySalesTaxTextBox.Text, out resulta))
{
    //take appropriate action here
}
if (!decimal.TryParse(stateSalesTaxTextBox.Text, out resultb))
{
    //take appropriate action here
}
if (!decimal.TryParse(comissionTextBox.Text, out resultc))
{
    //take appropriate action here
}
```

I'd like to take the opportunity to advise you to change your variable names:

- `resulta` should be `countySalesTaxRate`
- `resultb` should be `stateSalesTaxRate`
- `resultc` should be `commissionRate`

Comment: This is how I had it originally, but the end value isn't correct. i.e. its displaying 100 + 5 + 4 + 0 = 100 and it always comes out to the same value as the user entered data.

Comment: @JamaulSmith Then do you have code other than what you posted? I see nothing wrong with what we have here that would exhibit that kind of behaviour. EDIT: Are you _sure_ that your inputs for `5` and `4` are correct? If you have bad text being parsed, they'll stay 0 and you'll have `100 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 100`

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I updated the code I had available. They should be valid, but they probably aren't.

Comment: @JamaulSmith I suspect that Chris Sinclair is correct.  If the parse fails, you'll get a sum of 100.  This would be the expected behavior if Parse is throwing a format exception; tryparse would return false and give a value of zero.  What did you have in the `//take appropriate action here` spots?

Comment: @phoog: I'm guessing "`//take appropriate action here`" :P

Comment: @JamaulSmith Run the program in debug mode and put a break point where you parse it. Check what the _actual value is at runtime_ for those text fields. What you find may lead you to the solution.

Comment: @phoog  I know this is extremely stupid, but I have absolutely no clue what to put in place of //take appropriate action here and I took your advice on renaming my variables, you're awesome. <3

Comment: @JamaulSmith You need to check your input. What are the _actual runtime_ values being reported by `stateSalesTaxTextBox.Text` and `comissionTextBox.Text`? For `//take appropriate action here` report to the user that they need to input a _number_.

Comment: @JamaulSmith sorry, I was offline for the weekend. Chris Sinclair is correct. The point of `//Take the appropriate action...` is this: In your original code, an exception is thrown because *the string being parsed is invalid*, and you are ignoring that fact. With my code, an invalid string *causes control to flow into the block containing the "take appropriate action" comment.* In either case, it's your job as the programmer to decide what to do with invalid content. Two common ways of handling it are (1) ignore it, because the user is not finished typing or (2) tell the user to change it.

Comment: @JamaulSmith However, ignoring the invalid string does not mean to just proceed with the method as your original code does -- your original code ignores the invalidity of the string, but it still sets the text of the `totalPriceCheckBox`.  Rather, if the input is invalid, your code should *stop trying to set the text of the totalPriceCheckBox.*  In other words, the method should return before the last statement (or possibly bypass the last statement with an `if` or other conditional).

Answer (score 3):

```
decimal resulta = 0;
decimal resultb = 0;
decimal resultc = 0;

decimal.TryParse(countySalesTaxTextBox.Text, out resulta);
decimal.TryParse(stateSalesTaxTextBox.Text, out resultb);
decimal.TryParse(comissionTextBox.Text, out resultc);
```

If it can't Parse the value, it will remain 0.  TryParse returns a true if it successfully parses, so if you want to display a message when it doesn't, just check for `TryParse == false`

Comment: In fact, there's no need to initialize the variables to 0 since that will be overwritten (i.e., if you initialize to some other value, TryParse will set the variable to zero if it returns `false`)

Comment: Indeed. In fact, I make a point to make sure that if I _intend_ to assign a variable a value as a result of a `TryParse`, that I do _not_ give it a default value when declaring it. This ensures that I make sure to have it assigned _somewhere_ as opposed to accidentally forgetting it.

Comment: +1. if you want to be paranoid - set 0 value on TryParse returning false, not before - `out` means it is guaranteed to be set to something after function returns (which is in case of TryParse is documented to be 0).

Answer (score 3):

Just some extra information, before you bump into culture issues with . and ,

Use the Decimal.TryParse overload like this

```
Decimal.TryParse(countySalesTaxTextBox.Text, NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("en-US"), out resulta);
```

Comment: Wait what? maybe he wants culture invariant, maybe he wants system's configuration, maybe he* is not from USA. *: male name, I hope.

Comment: True, but this is just an example when you know your LOB app will only be used in a specific country and you want to avoid supporting decimal issues. The best thing would to use usercontrols in the frontend that takes care of all the parsing. Full with masks and edit restrictions.

Comment: +1 to mentioning culture setting. One will need to get proper culture for each case. Likely for UI application just using current culture (by simply not specifying it) is correct choice, but knowing about the behavior is useful.

Answer (score 3):

You have several different issues:

First, the `FormatException` is occurring because you are passing a non-numeric value to the `decimal.Parse()` method.  You need to check your inputs.

Next, in your example, you are effectively swallowing your exception.  It is thrown, the catch clock catches it, but since you don't do anything within the block, your code just leaves the catch block and continues.  Because of this, your `totalPrice` is still calculated with default values for the variables that were not calculated due to the exception.

As others have suggested, `decimal.TryParse()` is a much better option as it will not throw an exception.  But you need to decide what you want to do when one of the `Parse()` or `TryParse()` method calls fails.  Do you want to assume that the result is zero, or do you want to abort the calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (!decimal.TryParse(countySalesTaxTextBox.Text, out resulta)) { /*Resolve issue*/ }
if (!decimal.TryParse(stateSalesTaxTextBox.Text, out resultb)) { /*Resolve issue*/ }
if (!decimal.TryParse(comissionTextBox.Text, out resultc)) { /*Resolve issue*/ }
```

Double check my variable names and default values.

Comment: You need to use the `out` keyword with the second parameter of TryParse.

Comment: Also, no point in assigning `0` if the parse fails; if it fails `0` will be assigned automatically.

Comment: Also, if TryParse returns false, the variable will already be `0`; no need to assign it again.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair beat me by 15 seconds!

Comment: `resultX = 0` should be instead "do something sensible in case of parsing failure"...